# Youtube script of setting speed not working

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

So this code is ment to create a range input and a text node. So the input range is the value of the speed i want to change but when ever i run the code it says the `setmyspeed()` is not defined.

```
//Better youtube
//Creating elements
function createtext() {
    var text = document.createTextNode("Speed:");
    document.getElementById("eow-title").appendChild(text);
}
function createrange() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("id", "speedrange");
    input.setAttribute("type", "range");
    input.setAttribute("onchange", "setmyspeed()");
    input.setAttribute("max", "5");
    input.setAttribute("step", "0.1");
    input.setAttribute("min", "0.1");
    input.setAttribute("value", "1");
    document.getElementById("eow-title").appendChild(input);
}
//Running the fuctions
createtext()
createrange()
//Feature functions
setmyspeed()
{
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    var speed = document.getElementById("speedrange").value;
    video.playbackRate =  + (speed);
    document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = "Speed:(" + speed + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`createtext()`, `createrange()`, `setmyspeed()` are all calls for methods. You are not getting any errors on `createtext()` or `createrange()` because you have these function created created starting lines `function createtext() {...` and  `createrange() {....`.

You do **not**, however, have `setmyspeed()` created.

If you add the following code before your `setmyspeed()` call your error will disappear, but you still need to put some code into brackets to make it do something.

```
function setmyspeed() {
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no function `setmyspeed()`

```
setmyspeed()
{
    // ...
}
```

is call to function and useless parentheses to wrap code. You are missing `function` keyword before `setmyspeed()`:

```
function setmyspeed()
{
    // ...
}
```